# Can I reuse the rest api and database

Tags: angularjs, cordova, slim

I have a dynamic website which is coded using angularjs and html as frontend and rest api as backend. And using mysql as database.

I need to convert the website contents to app. I thought of doing the same in phonegap.

Can I use the same database and rest api for building the app ?

Comment: you can use the database and the rest api for phonegap as well. Remember that you cannot use the mysql database in the mobile phone. The db will reside on the webserver.

Comment: So there is no way to reuse mysql database? my rest api returns the data in json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse your REST api with an phonegap app.

**However,** if you are familiar with angularjs, it will be much easier for your to work with ionic framework which wraps cordova plugins with an angularjs based webview. so you can reuse some of your web code (or not).

> http://ionicframework.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is posible to use the Rest api. If you access the database only from that rest api it is posible to keep the database as well.